# Why expression delegat match faster than il-code

Tags: c#, .net, expression, cil

I Have next test code:

```
    public static void Test1()
    {
        var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a");
        var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int,int,int>>(Expression.Block(Expression.Add(a,b)),a,b);
        var f = expression.Compile();
        f(1,2);
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue/10; i++)
        {
            f(1, 2);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("TestExpression - {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    public static void Test2()
    {
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("Add", typeof(int), new[] {typeof(int), typeof(int)}, true);

        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var f = (Func<int, int, int>) dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate(f);
        f(1, 2);

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue / 10; i++)
        {
            f(1, 2);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("TestIl - {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
```

And Timing: 617 ms vs 880ms. 
Do you have any ideas?
I check net source code:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,c5ff378c3a5f8142

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs,65b74d122162a33d
Thanks, a lot.

Comment: Did you compare the real machine code produced by the JIT for both situations?

Comment: Yes. I did. Code the same. Row by row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187448/17034

Comment: How I can improve performance il-code in this case? (Except use x86)

Comment: I am trying this "dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), new object())" and got this exception: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Comment: @Hans: so, is it your assertion that in the `Expression` scenario, the delegate instance is being created with a target? If so, could you elaborate on that? Or are you simply pointing out that different techniques result in differences in the broader execution environment (generated code, stubs/thunks, ancillary objects, etc.) that confound attempts to compare performance between seemingly equivalent operations?

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Question is closet. I Find out how it is working. I do not know how to mark question as solved.